# How can i stop my player from clicking buttons under a widget in Unreal engine

Tags: widget, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

Im making a game that simulates a desktop in unreal. I am making it that the player can open programs and they will display in thier own windows that can be moved around just like on a real desktop. The problem is that if the window is over a button  on the desktop, the player can click it even when the widget is covering the button. I need it so that the player can not click the button when there is a window covering it. But i want the button to be clckable when the window is not covering it(like how it works on a real desktop.). I know i can make the button not clickable by using `not hit testable` but i need code that can tell if the button is covered by another widget. What would be the best way to do this (preferably something that can be done using blueprints in unreal.).

Thanks,
Matthew

Edit. Thanks for you answers. Just adding to the question. What visibility should I use for the background to make sure the widget on top take all the click events? Thanks again.

Comment: The easier way is to have the background of your window be hit testable. If configured with the right visibility settings, a widget that is on top of another widget should consume the click event, so that it doesn't reach the widget under it.